# Retrieving value of specific column from selected row in html

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following table in html5

```
name roll address
a     1    pune
b     2    pune
c     3    pune
```

Now I select the third row of the table with mouse with name c.
The id of table is `table1`, I want to retrieve the second column of selected row from the table.

Please help me resolve this with jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is the HTML code

```
<table id="table1">
    <tr>
        <td>name</td>
        <td>roll</td>
        <td>address</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>pune</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>pune</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>pune</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The following script will alert the second column of the clicked row

```
$('#table1 tr').on('click', function(){
    alert($(this).children().first().next().html());
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jLt5bkqp/2/

Or you can also use [:nth-child() Selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)

```
$('#table1 tr').on('click', function(){
    alert($(this).children('td:nth-child(2)').html());
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jLt5bkqp/3/

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$("table1 tr").on("click", "td:nth-child(2)", function(e) {
    alert($(this).html()); 
});
```